# Arguments to a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am new to creating functions in R. I was building an algorithm in a function and noticed something strange. Below is a simplified example of it.

I have two matrices I want to scalar multiply using a function.

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3,ncol=3)
matrix <- matrix(c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2),nrow=3,ncol=3)
```

My function:

```
Amatrix <- function(){
    a_matrix <- A*matrix
}
```

Calling the function:

```
matrix_2 <- Amatrix()
```

The output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    6   12   18
```

My question is, how come I don't need to give 'A' and 'matrix' as arguments to my function?

Is it correct to assume that even though arguments are not needed for a function to work as intended, it is bad practice to omit them?

Comment: You defined `A` and `matrix` outside the scope of your function. If `R` doesn't find an object in the function scope, it goes backward to see if the object exists in the calling environment (i.e. the scope in which the function has been called). There, R found the objects named in the function body. Needless to say, your practice is not recommended: you should define clearly the function arguments: `Amatrix<-function(A,B) return(A*B)`. Also, don't call objects (like `matrix`) with names that are used for base R functions.

Comment: The section `Name masking` from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping describes this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongzyy,

> How come I don't need to give 'A' and 'matrix' as arguments to my function?

Languages such as R support the concept of `scope`. In the example given, the variables `A` and `matrix` have global scope thus can be seen within the function`Amatrix`.

In general, when the object is assigned is not important. Where the object is assigned is important. Also important, is the state of the relevant environments when the function is evaluated. It also worth noting that `when` a function is defined, it is assigned to an object and treated like any other variable.

#### An Example of variable scope conflict:

Let's look at an example:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3,ncol=3)         # Global Scope
matrix <- matrix(c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2),nrow=3,ncol=3)    # Global Scope

Amatrix <- function(){
  matrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3,ncol=3)  # Local Scope
  a_matrix <- A*matrix                                  # Global * Local Scope
}

matrix_2 <- Amatrix()                                   # Returns Global*Local result
```

#### What is the result of executing the above program?

We observe an example of scope conflict. `A` has global scope
`matrix` within the function `Amatrix` is defined to have a local scope. The result will be to combine the combination of global `A` and local `matrix` which results in an answer of:

```
> matrix_2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   16   49
[2,]    4   25   64
[3,]    9   36   81
>
```

as opposed to:

```
> matrix_2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    6   12   18
```

> Is it correct to assume that even though arguments are not needed for a function to work as intended, it is bad practice to omit them?

In general, it is bad practice to use global variables. In some cases you need global variables, just step carefully.

The principle problem is tracking when and how global variables were changed and by whom. Consider, if you write four functions all accessing your data, which updated the matrix last? Tricky to know exactly.

If you were to run your program in parallel you would hit problems very quickly as parallel access to global data structures creates some remarkably novel problems.

I hope the above helps.
Take care